# casting mysql column string that has zeroes in it

Tags: mysql, casting

I have a column with value suppose "0082-A",

casting this value to integer gives 82, what I need is the value 0082,

`CAST( column as UNSIGNED)`

Comment: You want everything before the first hyphen? If so use substring_index

Comment: What about `select REGEXP_REPLACE(col1, '[^0-9]+', '')  from test;` ? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=36c92791c980efe52806b2778ad4859f

Comment: @ErgestBasha mysql version is 5.7, cant use `REGEXP_REPLACE`.

Comment: *what I need is the value 0082* `0082` is not numeric value, this is string value.

Comment: If you need the substring from the beginning till first dash then use SUBSTRING_INDEX() function.